# Excel VBA Equal times do not match

Tags: vba, datetime, excel

I have this VBA code in Excel:

```
If (TimeValue(C_CurrentDate) = L_CurrentStartTime) Then
   do-someting
End If
```

But it never does "something".

Example data are C_CurrentDate -> 17/03/2014 2:05:00 and L_CurrentStartTime -> 2:05:00

Both sides of the comparison should be 2:05:00 but it still does not match.
I have even converted them both to double in a msgbox and they both present 8,68055555555556E-02

Their difference as Doble values is in the E-17 range.

How could it be that? Both values have been read from cell data.

Comment: what do you get if you compare `TimeValue(C_CurrentDate) = TimeValue(L_CurrentStartTime)`

Comment: @Fred, I'd be curious to know, as well. When I tried it using the values @Envite gave, I got a `Type Mismatch` error on 2:05:00, even though I made sure it was formatted properly.

Comment: @tmoore82 Values are read from cells and then casted using CDate. TimeValue on a String will cause Type Mismatch anyway.

Comment: @Fred they still do not match. They still have a difference below one millionth of a second.

Answer (score 2):

Just discard the date part of the combined DateTime:

```
Sub TestOfTime()
    Dim C_CurrentDate As String, L_CurrentStartTime As String
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date

    C_CurrentDate = "17/03/2014 2:05:00"
    L_CurrentStartTime = "2:05:00"

    d1 = TimeValue(Split(C_CurrentDate, " ")(1))
    d2 = TimeValue(L_CurrentStartTime)
    If d1 = d2 Then
        MsgBox "Same Time"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: C_CurrentDate is not a String, but a DateTime, so I can not use Split.

Comment: @Envite:  That is my very point!  In **VBA** ,you can treat it as a string and perform the extraction.  In something like **c#** that would not be the case.   Are you using **VBA** ?

Comment: Yes, VBA. Your solution works, but the question is why does this happen. Same hour should mean same decimal part in the DateTime value.

Comment: It depends on where the data comes from....is it an external source or a worksheet cell or a user input??

Comment: Data are pasted as text in cells from a report. Then readed with Cell.Value and casted with CDate

Comment: EXCELLENT!!...You can read them in with **Cell.Text** and then use my **String** technique.

Answer (score 0):

It is curious that you'd have to split the date out to make it work. A solution is a solution, so @Gary's Student has provided the answer that will let you move forward. But if the *why* is going to torture you (as it would me), you'd have to share more of your process. For example, I took your two samples, `17/03/2014 2:05:00` and `2:05:00` and pasted them as text into cells `B2` and `B3` of a workbook, and ran the following:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim C_CurrentDate As Date
C_CurrentDate = CDate(Range("B2").Value)
Dim L_CurrentStartTime As Date
L_CurrentStartTime = CDate(Range("B3").Value)

Debug.Print C_CurrentDate
Debug.Print CDate(Range("B2").Value)
Debug.Print TimeValue(Range("B2").Value)

Debug.Print L_CurrentStartTime
Debug.Print CDate(Range("B3").Value)

If TimeValue(Range("B2").Value) = CDate(Range("B3").Value) Then
    Debug.Print "True"
End If

If TimeValue(C_CurrentDate) = L_CurrentStartTime Then
    Debug.Print "True"
End If


End Sub
```

Both of my `If` statements resolve to `True`, and it sounds like you're basically getting your values the same way. If we could see more of what you're doing, we might be able to help you pinpoint the why. Of course, no guarantees. :)